# nodemon app crashes while trying to require mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My app keeps crashing when I try to require mongoose to my application.

I already installed my mongodb and it seems to be working fine since I get a response when I run the mongo command on my command prompt.

```
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

//Database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vidjot-dev', {
    useMongoClient: True
})
.then(() => console.log('Mongodb connected....'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
 throw err;
 ^
 Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\vidjot\app.js:3:18)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Did you do `npm install mongoose`?

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to run the following command in the desired directory

```
npm i mongoose
```

Run the application

OR

Try installing the module :

```
npm i -g mongoose
```

Then go to the directory of the application

```
npm link mongoose
```

Finally, run the application.